# glReadBuffer vs glReadBufferNV in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, openscenegraph

I'm trying to build OpenSceneGraph 3.2 for the Ubuntu armhf architecture, but I'm getting a compile error about a symbol not found. The symbol in question is `glReadBuffer`. I looked at `GLES2/gl2.h` header, and indeed, that symbol is not there. However, the symbol is present in `GLES3/gl3.h`, and documentation online suggests that the function was added in OpenGL ES 3.0. However, I did find a function named `glReadBufferNV` in `GLES2/gl2ext.h` (which is not `#include`'d in the source files.

I'm wondering if `glReadBufferNV` can be used instead of `glReadBuffer`, and what might be the possible side effects. I'm suspecting that the `NV` stands for Nvidia, and that it is a Nvidia-only implementation. Is this correct? If so, is there any way to get `glReadBuffer` in OpenGL ES 2.0 (I am under the impression that OpenSceneGraph can be built under OpenGL ES 2.0)?

Edit: As it turned out, the code that builds this portion of OpenSceneGraph was excluded when building with OpenGL ES or OpenGL 3.0. However, I'm still interested in what's special about `glReadBufferNV`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your research suggests, `glReadBuffer` was added to ES for 3.0; it is not defined in 2.0. Prior to that, as per the header file you found, an extension defined `glReadBufferNV` — specifically [the NV_read_buffer extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/NV_read_buffer.txt).

So what's happened is that something wasn't in the spec, at least Nvidia thought it would be useful, so they've implemented an OpenGL extension, which has subsequently been discussed at Khronos, had all the edge cases or ambiguities dealt with and has eventually made its way into the core spec.

That's generally how GL development proceeds: extensions come along to provide functionality that's not yet in the main library, they're discussed and refined and adopted into the core spec if appropriate.

Comparing [the official specification for `glReadBuffer`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glReadBuffer.xhtml) with the extension documentation, the extension has a few ties into other extensions that you wouldn't expect to make it into the core spec (e.g. `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi_NV` is supported as a source) but see resolved issue 7:

> Version 6 of this specification isn't compatible with OpenGL ES 3.0.
>          For contexts without a back buffer, this extension makes FRONT the
>          default read buffer. ES 3.0 instead calls it BACK.
>          How can this be harmonized?
>
> RESOLVED: Update the specification to match ES 3.0 behavior. This
>         introduces a backwards incompatibility, but few applications are
>         expected to be affected. In the EGL ecosystem where ES 2.0 is
>         prevalent, only pixmaps have no backbuffer and their usage remains
>         limited.

So the extension has retroactively been modified to bring it into line with what was agreed for the core spec.